# smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required.) in flask

Tags: python, flask, python-os, flask-mail

I see many solutions but still, I have a problem for send mail and I also set email and password to 
~/.bash_profile so please help me.

Here my connfig.py file code

```
import os

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY=os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 465
    MAIL_USE_SSL= True  
    MAIL_USERNAME=os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
    MAIL_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

I also try the google two-step verification and app password still I have a problem. What can I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when I debugged my code I found that my `os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')` was empty. Make sure it has your exact credentials.

What I did was hardcoding my username and password (it is not recommended to do it for security purposes) :

```
class Config:

    SECRET_KEY=os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 465
    MAIL_USE_SSL= True  
    MAIL_USERNAME='youremailhere'
    MAIL_PASSWORD='yourpasswordemailhere'
```

... and then make sure you have the Less Secure App Access turned on in your google account, you'll find it here -> https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: Yeah, after changing the environment variable. I need to restart my VScode and then it's working properly. I hope this helps.